# VSCode + Gradle Java Run and Debug

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make VSCode work with using a Gradle build file using Java with modules (from Java version 11). The gradle.build compile works just fine, but I cannot make VSCode execute the output compiled Java class files. (It always tries to create its own.)

VSCode version: 1.48.2

System Info: Ubuntu 2020.04

Java Build:

```
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
def version = 0.1

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/easytext/javamodularity/easytext'
        }
    }
}
```

module-info.java located at $projectDir/src/easytext/module-info.java

```
// module easytext {
module easytext.javamodularity.easytext {
    requires java.base;
}
```

Really simple Main.java, located at $projectDir/src/easytext/javamodularity/easytext/Main.java:

```
//package easytext;
package easytext.javamodularity.easytext;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to EasyText. Please provide a filename as input argument.");
            return;
        }

}
```

The gradle file always wants to output to **$projectDir/build/**, but VScode always wants to run the files in $projectDir/bin/easytext/javamodularity/easytext/Main.class.

I am also getting the VSCode error which I do not understand: "module-info.java is not on the classpath of project EasyText, only syntax errors are reported."

Running the Gradle task 'build' does compile successfully.

I do not have a launch.json file because I am a loss for how to point it to the modulePath? Or is there some sort of magic I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

If you are properly configured to debug gradle tasks, you will see a debug icon next to the run icon in the gradle Tasks list.  To get to the gradle task list, click on the Gradle logo in the extensions bar (indicated by *yellow* arrow).  The *red* arrow shows the debug task.

[image]

VSCode is not necessarily configured to display this option. There are 3 places this can be configured.

1. The User `settings.json` file.
2. The Workspace `settings.json` file.
3. The remote machine's `settings.json` file. (Only applicable if developing on a remote server)

These files can be edited by

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open the settings window.
2. Type `gradle.javaDebug` in the search bar.
3. Select User, Remote[SSH:yourhosthere], or Workspace as desired.
4. Click `Edit in settings.json`
5. Add the following code inside the top level curly brackets.

**Note 1:** While typing, you will get the option to auto complete the rest of the configuration.  Additionally, if there are other entries in your `settings.json` file, make sure you include a comma as appropriate.

```
{
  "gradle.javaDebug": {
    "tasks": [
      "run",
      "runBoot",
      "test",
      "intTest",
      "integration"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note 2:** If you have a subproject, you should add the `"gradle.javaDebug"` entry into the Workspace `settings.json`.  The entry would look something like the following.

```
{
  "gradle.javaDebug": {
    "tasks": [
      "run",
      "runBoot",
      "test",
      "intTest",
      "integration",
      "subprojectname:run",
      "subprojectname:test"
    ]
  }
}
```

This was tested using Visual Studio Code Version: 1.61.2.  If the changes to the `settings.json` do not fix your problem, there is an open issue (as of the time of this posting) that may be related to your issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gradle/issues/876

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but i had the same problem, here is my solution if anyone needs it.

1)Install the gradle vscode [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardwillis.vscode-gradle)

2)open the gradle tasks and here you have the run/debug options
[image]

Alternatively you could run the task from terminal using

**Linux**

./gradlew build

./gradlew run

**Windows**

gradlew.bat build

gradlew.bat run